# Adding labels to the geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I have some difficulties with the labels for this [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoWEd.png). Specifically, the labels do not fit in their corresponding bar. Also, it looks like the labels are not in a right place. In other words, the percentage for non-Hispanic Whites should appear in the orange boxes.

Thanks,

MRR

```
IDD_line_race <-
  ggplot(race_2010, aes(x =Year_  , y =per_X_ , fill=race_new2), colour="black",
         stat="identity", width=0.9,  position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(y = per_X_, label = paste0(format(per_X_),"%")), colour = "white")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#F76900","#000E54")) + 
  labs(
    x = "Year",
    y = "Population 65+ (%)",
    caption = (""),
    face = "bold"
  ) +
  theme_classic()+
  coord_flip()

IDD_line_race
```

Comment: `geom_col` infers from the fact you have multiple series mapped to `fill` that each series should be stacked, i.e. it assumes `position = position_stack()`. The text layer doesn't make the same assumption, so it is not transforming the percents from their raw values into a "stacked" value. Is it resolved if you add `position = position_stack()` in the text layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `geom_col` by default uses `position = "stack"` while `geom_text` uses `position="identity"`. To put your labels at the correct positions you have to use `position = "stack"` or the more verbose `position = position_stack()` in `geom_text` too. Additionally I right aligned the labels using `hjust=1` and removed the clutter from the `ggplot()` call.

Using some fake example data:;

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

race_2010 <- data.frame(
  Year_ = rep(2010:2019, 2),
  race_new2 = rep(c("non-Hispanic Black", "non-Hispanic White"), each = 10),
  per_X_ = round(c(runif(10, 1, 2), runif(10, 9, 12)), 1)
)

ggplot(race_2010, aes(x =Year_  , y =per_X_ , fill=race_new2)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(y = per_X_, label = paste0(format(per_X_),"%")), colour = "white", position = position_stack(), hjust = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#F76900","#000E54")) + 
  labs(
    x = "Year",
    y = "Population 65+ (%)",
    caption = (""),
    face = "bold"
  ) +
  theme_classic()+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful. How can I fix values for year such that it increments by one year instead of 2.5 years.

Comment: You are welcome. You could set the number or your desired breaks using `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(race_2010$Year_))`.